# How do I get ASP.Net MVC to ignore the "&ui-page" added to the URL by jQuery Mobile?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile

I have an ASP.Net MVC site that uses **jQuery Mobile 1.3.**

In certain situations, jQuery Mobile will take you to the following URL:

```
http://{domain}/{controller}/{action}/{id}&ui-page={jQueryMobile.PageId}
```

How do I set up my web site so that MVC ignores the `&ui-page=` and everything after.

I believe the first step is to set things up so that a validation error is not thrown by MVC when a `"&"` is in the URL.  To do this, I add the following to web.config.

```
<system.web>
  <httpRuntime requestPathInvalidCharacters="&lt;,&gt;,*,%,:,\" />
```

However, after I do that, my next problem is that the `&` throws off my routing rules.

EDIT: I just have the default Route set up, so here is my route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
  name: "Default",
  url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
  defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Comment: Could you post your routing rules, an example url that throws an error and the text of the error thrown?

Comment: @CAbbott: I've updated the question with my route.  It's just the default route, though.

Comment: Could you post the error you're receiving? By default the automapper in MVC will just not map any additional parameters you pass in an httppost; it won't throw an error.

Comment: @CAbbott: Just to clarify: You see that the {id} and the &ui-page are concatenated, right?  So for example: {action}/225&ui-page=blah

Comment: @CAbbott: In answer to your question, the error I get is that it can't parse an {id} or find an {id} that is a Guid or something like that.  The reason, of course, is because the Guid has the "&ui-page" at the end of it.  If I get creative and insert a "c" in between the two (e.g. "{action}/235/&ui-page") then I get a 404.

Comment: is it possible to add ? before the & ? like in this url sample : http://{domain}/{controller}/{action}/{id}?&ui-page={jQueryMobile.PageId} it could also be a #

Comment: @VinnyG: I've spent hours and hours trying to get jQueryMobile to do either one of these.  I'll continue trying... but I was hoping there was just something I could do with my MVC route so that it works without the ? or #.